@foreach Isn't Doing Everything for each record
I have a razor page that is looking at a list of people and their votes. It is bringing up items like Municipality, Supervisor, Simple Majority, 2/3 Majority just fine, but when it comes to SelectedVote, it only puts the value in the first record, not the rest. SelectedVote is based on the DDL of VoteType. The Selected Vote value is also missing when the page loads - even though it is my understanding that "onchange" will also do "onload". Am I incorrect? Could someone please point me to what I am missing? Please be gentle. I am trying my best and I have spent hours reading and trying things before I posted this.

My ultimate objective is the user just needs to click the radio button for each supervisor record and it fills in the appropriate vote number (from the selected vote column) in either the yes, no or abstain columns. I know I have a lot to figure out yet.
.cshtml and section script follows:
<form method="post">
    <input hidden asp-for="Vote.VoteId" />
        <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
            <div class="row pb-2">
                <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Enter Votes</h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
            <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                <tr>                   
                    <td style="width: 75%">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="Vote.VoteDesc"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Vote.VoteDesc" id="VoteDesc" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Vote.VoteDesc" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 25%">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="Vote.SupervisorStatus"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Vote.SupervisorStatus" id="SupervisorStatus" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayStatusData.OrderBy(x => x.StatusDesc),"StatusDesc", "StatusDesc"))" onchange="assignSupervisorData()">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Supervisor Status---</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    <td style="width: 25%">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="Vote.VoteType"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Vote.VoteType" id="VoteType" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayVoteTypeData.OrderBy(x => x.VoteTypeDesc),"VoteTypeDesc", "VoteTypeDesc"))" onchange="assignVoteTypeData()">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Vote Type---</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 50%">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="Vote.Committee"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Vote.Committee" id="Committee" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayCommitteeData.OrderBy(x => x.CommitteeDesc),"CommitteeDesc", "CommitteeDesc"))">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Committee---</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            MUNICIPALITY
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SUPERVISOR
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SIMPLE
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            2/3
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SELECTED VOTE
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            ACTIVE VOTE
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            YES
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            NO
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            ABSTAIN
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var obj in Model.WorkingVote.OrderBy(i => i.Municipality))
                    {
                        <tr width="100%">
                            <td width="14%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.Municipality, new
                                    { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 125px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="14%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.SupervisorName, new
                                    { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 175px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.SimpleMajority, new
                                    { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "SimpleMajority", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 75px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.TwoThirdsMajority, new
                                    { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "TwoThirdsMajority", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 75px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class ="mb-3">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.SelectedVote, new
                                    { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "SelectedVote", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 100px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div id="ActiveVote" class="mb-3">
                                    <label>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => obj.ActiveVote, "Yes", new { id = "" })
                                        <span>YES</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => obj.ActiveVote, "No", new { id = "" })
                                        <span>NO</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => obj.ActiveVote, "Abstain", new { id = "" })
                                        <span>ABSTAIN</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.YesVote, new { id = "YesVote", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 100px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.NoVote, new { id = "NoVote", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 100px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="12%">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.AbsVote, new { id = "AbsVote", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 100px" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;">Update</button>
            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 150px;">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    @{
        var prevDisabled = !Model.WorkingVote.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var nextDisabled = !Model.WorkingVote.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
    }

    <a asp-page="./Index"
       asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.WorkingVote.PageIndex - 1)"
       class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled">
        Previous
    </a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a asp-page="./Index"
       asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.WorkingVote.PageIndex + 1)"
       class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled">
        Next
    </a>

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">   

        function assignVoteTypeData() {
            votetype = $("#VoteType").val();
            console.log(votetype)
            $("#SelectedVote").val(votetype).trigger('input');
        }

        function updateVoteTypeData() {
            let votes;
            if (votetype == "Simple Majority") {
                votes = parseFloat($("#SimpleMajority").val());
            }
            else {
                votes = parseFloat($("#TwoThirdsMajority").val());
            }
            $("#SelectedVote").val(votes);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SelectedVote').on('input', updateVoteTypeData);
        });

    </script>
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
}

.cs
[BindProperties]

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Vote Vote { get; set; }
    public ActiveVote ActiveVote { get; set; }
    public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
    public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public PaginatedList<WorkingVote>? WorkingVote { get; set; } = default!;

    public IEnumerable<Committee> DisplayCommitteeData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VoteType> DisplayVoteTypeData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Supervisor> DisplaySupervisorData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Status> DisplayStatusData { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(int Id, int? pageIndex)
    {
        Vote = _db.Vote.Find(Id);
        DisplayCommitteeData = await _db.Committee.ToListAsync();
        DisplayVoteTypeData = await _db.VoteType.ToListAsync();
        DisplaySupervisorData = await _db.Supervisor.ToListAsync();
        DisplayStatusData = await _db.Status.ToListAsync();

        IQueryable<WorkingVote> workingVote = (IQueryable<WorkingVote>)(from x in _db.Supervisor
                                           join y in _db.Vote on x.Status equals y.SupervisorStatus
                                           select new WorkingVote
                                           {
                                               VoteId = y.VoteId,
                                               VoteCode = y.VoteCode,
                                               VoteDate = y.VoteDate,
                                               VoteDesc = y.VoteDesc,
                                               VoteType = y.VoteType,
                                               Committee = y.Committee,
                                               Municipality = x.Municipality,
                                               SupervisorName = x.DisplayName,
                                               SimpleMajority = x.Simple,
                                               TwoThirdsMajority = x.TwoThirds,
                                               SelectedVote = y.Votes,
                                               ActiveVote = y.ActiveVote
                                           }); ;

        int casesPerPage = 20;
        WorkingVote = await PaginatedList<WorkingVote>.CreateAsync(
            workingVote, pageIndex ?? 1, casesPerPage);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Vote.Update(Vote);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Votes cast successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}

usings and extra fields have been eliminated for brevity. Please let me know if you need to see something else. Thanks!

IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't be using the same IDs in every row of the table.

Can you please give an example of what you mean? I don't see the same IDs on every row.

Doesn't @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.SelectedVote, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "SelectedVote", @class = "form-control", @dir = "rtl", @style = "width: 100px" }) give you id="SelectedVote on every row?

I was only getting the selected Vote number on the first row (the 95 under Selected Vote column in the screenshot above. Now, I am getting nothing with suggested changes below. Is the Id already inferred by the object name when using @Html.TexBoxFor ? I am new to using these.

I don't use Razor, but you probably don't need IDs in the repeated elements like this. You access them using classes and navigation relative to the event target.

According to the screenshot, it looks like that you want to have a feature which the table and it's content shall re-render after the radio option is changed, e.g. click yes then show  content filtered for yes. If so, here's a sample code. Razor page content requires to be loaded in the server side. So that we need to add onchange event, and then update the html content. The sample code get the html content in the ajax callback.

Yes, thanks. I need the DDL for Vote Type to change the Selected Vote value to either the Simple or 2/3 vote numbers. Then, when the user is actively recording votes, I would like the Active Vote radio button to fill the Yes, No and Abstain columns with the Selected Vote number when the user selects the radios for yes, no or abstain. Make sense? The Yes, No and Abstain columns COULD be filled with one refresh (maybe with a button RECORD VOTES?

Tbh, I can't understand the business logic of the VOTE, but if you want to trigger page content reload when radio button onchange event occurs, we need to reload the whole page by form submit or manually replace the table/row content via an ajax request. I mean we need to define the onchange event, and submit form or send ajax request to update the table content, because razor page renders the page in the server side.

This app will be used live, while the votes are being cast. This is for someone to record the votes. The Active Vote is to simply CONFIRM that the app is recording the correct amount, but that column could be eliminated as the actual vote columns should display the correct vote number once the user clicks on the YES, NO or ABSTAIN radio button.

Thank you for your confirmation, then have you tried to add onchange event handler for the radio buttons?

In your code assignVoteTypeData() sets the SelectedVote globally, Which is erroneous. That needs to be corrected as to set the value for that specific record. To do so refer the below code snippet:


function assignVoteTypeData(row) {
  let votetype = $(row).find(".vote-type").val();
  let selectedVote = $(row).find(".selected-vote");
  selectedVote.val(votetype);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.vote-type').on('change', function() {
    let row = $(this).closest('tr');
    assignVoteTypeData(row);
  });


  $('.vote-type').each(function() { // Set SelectedVote on page load event 
    let row = $(this).closest('tr');
    assignVoteTypeData(row);
  });
});



Also at the same time you need to initialize SelectedVote when the page loads. This can be achieved in the razor page itself via the following HTML along with the razor code snippet.


<select asp-for="Vote.VoteType" id="VoteType" class="form-select vote-type" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayVoteTypeData.OrderBy(x => x.VoteTypeDesc),"VoteTypeDesc", "VoteTypeDesc"))">
    <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Vote Type---</option>
</select>



Now set the SelectedVote value directly in your Razor loop like below:
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => obj.SelectedVote, new { @class = "form-control selected-vote", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width: 100px" })

Please do the above-mentioned corrections and check for the respective output.

Hello Selaka, I made your suggested edits, but now I don't get anything at all in the Selected Vote column. Was I supposed to replace my entire Javascript code with yours? I'm confused. I have also added a photo in my original post to further clarify what the program is supposed to do. I want to be sure you understand what I am trying to do. Thanks!
